# Roasted chickpeas for houmous?

Tags: chickpeas, hummus

I accidentally bought roasted, salted chickpeas (I've never heard of this - why would anyone want that?) instead of normal, dried chickpeas. To be clear, these chickpeas are dry and powdery, rather than boiled chickpeas roasted with salt to make a soft/crispy snack.

Can I still use them to make houmous? Or should I give this one up?

Comment: sounds like the little rocks could be ground and seasoned to make instant-dried-eat-only-in-emergency houmous.

Comment: @PatSommer What an awful idea. I can definitely imagine someone trying to market that ;)

Comment: At 3000 meters and hungry, it passes for food.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Roasted, salted dry chickpeas](http://nuts.com/snacks/chickpeas/golden-salted.html) are a snack food.

I would not expect for you to be able to make humus out of them; for one thing, they would have way too much salt, and the texture would be wrong.  It might be possible with a lot of experimentation, but you'd need to go through several failed batches before you got one which worked.  Personally, I'd just go back to the store.

Comment: I've had them soaking for 24 hours, and they seem OK (rehydrated). I'm going to pressure cook them, and see how it goes. I figure at that stage, I've basically lost nothing. But yes, I'm going to pick up some proper chickpeas when I'm next shopping.

Comment: Having cooked them (in a pressure cooker), the texture is about right, but they have a washed-out flavour.

Comment: @Marcin perhaps add that as an answer?

Comment: "I've basically lost nothing" - except a potentially tasty snack...

Answer (score 5):

I soaked the roasted chickpeas for 24 hours or so, with a few changes of water, and they seemed to rehydrate just fine.

I cooked them in a pressure cooker until tender (overall, about 50 minutes, in 15 minute stretches), and they ended up with about the right texture, but with a washed-out taste, and the water looked like a thin, white, chickpea broth. I didn't waste any ingredients trying to actually turn that into houmous.

Answer (score 0):

I should think this is a viable way to make hummus.

Check out this [recipe](http://www.food.com/recipe/roasted-hummus-167775) for Roasted chickpea hummus.

Comment: Any comments on taste differences?

Comment: Hey thanks, but the chickpeas are already dry and roasted.

Comment: different 'roasted' altogether